# Ajuda com $_SESSION

Tags: php

Quero pegar os valores de um formulário e passar em outra página do meu site, mas sempre dá erro.

Código onde está os valores:

```
<form id="formulario" name="form" action="login.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validacao()"/>

<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['bairro'] = $_POST['tBairro'];
   $_SESSION['rua'] = $_POST['tRua'];
   $_SESSION['numero'] = $_POST['tNum'];
   $_SESSION['cidade'] = $_POST['tCidade'];
   $_SESSION['estado'] = $_POST['tEstado'];

?>
```

Código onde quero passar os valores:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo '<span>Endereço para a entrega 01: ' . echo $_SESSION['bairro'];  '-' . echo $_SESSION['rua']; ',' echo $_SESSION['numero']; . '-'  . echo $_SESSION['cidade'] . '/' . echo $_SESSION['estado'];'</span>'
?>
```

Erro:

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)
```

O que eu posso fazer?

Comment: É necessário apenas o primeiro echo, os demais estão errados. É uma concatenação e não impressão.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta retirando o ; do final da variavel session. Quando vc utiliza ele desta foram vc esta finalizando o echo junto.
Edit: Como disse o colega, é necessário apenas um echo para iniciar a concatenação. Os demais podem ser removidos

segue:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo '<span>Endereço para a entrega 01: ' . $_SESSION['bairro'] .  '-' . $_SESSION['rua']. ','. $_SESSION['numero'] . '-'  .  $_SESSION['cidade'] . '/' . $_SESSION['estado'] '</span>' ;
?>
```

Comment: O seu exemplo ainda tem 2 `echos`.

Comment: Opa, obrigado, editado!

Answer (score 1):

tenta assim provavelmente não vai dar erro nenhum

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
?>
<span>Endereço para a entrega 01:
<?php echo $_SESSION['bairro'];?> -
<?php echo $_SESSION['rua'];?> ,
<?php echo $_SESSION['numero'];?> -
<?php echo $_SESSION['cidade'];?> /
<?php echo $_SESSION['estado'];?>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apenas um echo é necessário! Para ficar mais legível, faça assim:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo '<span>Endereço para a entrega 01: '
           .$_SESSION['bairro']
           .'-'.$_SESSION['rua']
           .','.$_SESSION['numero']
           .'-'.$_SESSION['cidade']
           .'/'.$_SESSION['estado']
       .'</span>';
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Resolvido! Deixei apenas um `echo` e finalizei o `;` no fim do `< /span` > e funcionou.